# adding column to pandas dataframe that enumerates based on unique values in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

first question, sorry if I missed it while searching for an answer.

I have a dataframe with a column called 'id', with each id appearing several times. I'm trying to add a column to this dataframe that basically represents the sequence of occurrences of each unique 'id'. For example:

```
id:      1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3
count:   1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1
```

Sorry for horrible formatting, I'm so exhausted at this point, any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: df['count']=df.groupby('id').cumcount()+1

Comment: Thanks Wen, I actually just found that answer this morning, sorry for the duplicate guys!

Here's the URL to the original that I found for those that are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598140/pandas-incrementally-count-occurrences-in-a-column