# Count text records in a column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, frequency, countif

I need to count how many times a value appears in the column. I did something similar in Excel and I want to understand how to play in pandas. Thanks

[image]

Comment: First do the research! E.g. search here on SO for: [`[python] [pandas] text occurrence`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%5Bpandas%5D+text+occurrence). Then __play with pandas__ and show your [example]. There are yet unclear requirements: Occurrence in entire column or up to the current row (like in your Excel formula) ?

Answer (score 1):

**You can try something like this:**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'char_list':list('aabbbbssbbaaabdddcccsbcderfffrrcashhttyy')})
df = df['char_list'].value_counts().reset_index()
df.columns = ['char_list', 'count']

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   char_list  count
0          b      8
1          a      6
2          c      5
3          s      4
4          d      4
5          r      3
6          f      3
7          h      2
8          t      2
9          y      2
10         e      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,1,1,4,5,6,2,1]})
oc = df.groupby("a").size
df["count"]=df["a"].map(oc)
print(oc)
print()
print(df)
```

to get

```
a
1    4
2    2
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    1
dtype: int64

   a  count
0  1      4
1  2      2
2  3      1
3  1      4
4  1      4
5  4      1
6  5      1
7  6      1
8  2      2
9  1      4
```

or do you prefer something like that [Pandas: Incrementally count occurrences in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598140/pandas-incrementally-count-occurrences-in-a-column) with an increment of occurrences ?

Comment: thanks man. It worked out

Answer (score 0):

### Clarify and describe your requirements

Count the occurrence of string X inside what?
Where to look, how to count?
What is X?

#### What does your Excel formula?

Your Excel formula is doing a **window-based** aggregation, where the aggregation function is a **count** (function `COUNT.IF`) and the window is from *first row* until **current row** (first parameter of type *range*). The counted (given criteria) is specified per row (second parameter as cell value).

See Excel's function [`COUNTIF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34):

> Counts the number of cells within a range that meet the given criteria

#### Illustrate by example

Instead of "window-based" we could also say cumulative:
The formula counts the occurrence of *string* `key123` (value in column `A`, current row, e.g. `1`) in rows between first (`$A$1`) to current (`$A1`).

Given a column with strings where the first string is `key123`, then

- its first occurrence should have count `1`,
- the second should have count `2`
- and so on

### Equivalent functions in pandas

So your Excel formula `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A1; A1)` would directly translate to pandas [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) like

`df.groupby("Column_A").cumcount()+1`

as already answered in:
[Pandas: Incrementally count occurrences in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598140/pandas-incrementally-count-occurrences-in-a-column)

### Terminology

The **cumulative count** increases the count for each occurrence. Similar to a *cumulative sum* also known as *running total*.

See also related SQL keywords/concepts:

- GROUP BY: grouping records and applying aggregate-functions
- COUNT: an aggregate-function like SUM, AVG, MAX, MIN
- window functions: allow further fine-grained aggregation